# Calling Java EE REST service through jQuery AJAX by passing the parameters from input text box

Tags: java, ajax, rest, web-services, jakarta-ee

I have an html code to create an input text box that accepts the input form user.And the parameters must be passed along with url to rest service.
This is my ajax call code:

```
$(function() {

var empid = document.getElementById("ManagerId").value;
$('#submit').click(function(){ 
$.ajax({ 
    crossDomain : true,
     type: "GET",
     dataType: "json",
    url: "http://localhost:8088/JirasTrackingApp/reporter/Reportees?empid="+empid,

     success: function(result){        
        console.log(result);
        document.write(empid.value);
     }
 });
});
```

This is my Service:

```
@Path("/Reportees")
public class ReporteesService {
    ReporteeList   reportee = new ReporteeList();

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Map<Object, Object> getList(String empid) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("id is"+empid);  //when I try to print the empid,it  displays nothing
        Map<Object, Object> map=reportee.getReportees(empid);  
        return map;             
    }
});
```

This is my getReportees() in ReporteeList class

```
public class ReporteeList {

    public Map<Object, Object> getReportees(String idOfEmp) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(idOfEmp);
        String msg = "error";
        String api = "https://connect.ucern.com/api/core/v3/people/";
        String id = idOfEmp;
        String ext = "/@reports";
        String url = api + id + ext;
        String name = "*********";
        String password = "*********";
        String authString = name + ":" + password;
        String authStringEnc = new BASE64Encoder().encode(authString.getBytes());
        System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " + authStringEnc);
        Client restClient = Client.create();
        WebResource webResource = restClient.resource(url);
        ClientResponse resp = webResource.accept("application/json")
                                         .header("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc)
                                         .get(ClientResponse.class);
        if (resp.getStatus() != 200) {
            System.err.println("Unable to connect to the server");
        }
        String output = resp.getEntity(String.class);

        // JSONParser reads the data from string object and break each data into key
        // value pairs
        JSONParser parse = new JSONParser();
        // Type caste the parsed json data in json object
        JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject) parse.parse(output);
        // Store the JSON object in JSON array as objects (For level 1 array element i.e list)

        JSONArray jsonarr_s = (JSONArray) jobj.get("list");
        Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<Object, Object>(); //error in this line 

        if (jsonarr_s.size() > 0) {

            // Get data for List array
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarr_s.size(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonobj_1 = (JSONObject) jsonarr_s.get(i);
                JSONObject jive = (JSONObject) jsonobj_1.get("jive");
                Object names = jsonobj_1.get("displayName");
                Object userid = jive.get("username");
                map.put(names, userid);                  
            }

            return map;
        } else {
            map.put("errorcheck", msg);
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

The value `empid` from the ajax call is not being taken by the service. And please tell me how to catch the parameters from the url and pass to the rest services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will also have to specify the `@QueryParam` annotation to your `getList` method:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Map<Object, Object> getList(@QueryParam("empId") String empid) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("id is"+empid);  //when I try to print the empid,it  displays nothing
    Map<Object, Object> map=reportee.getReportees(empid);  
    return map;             
}
```